# iPhone screen shot error. <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage

EDIT ANSWER:

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImageView *)maskImage withMask:(UIImageView *)cropImage
{

    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIImage *imagePNG = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(cropImage.frame.size.width, cropImage.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, 0.0); //retina res
    [self.viewForImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();


    NSData *imgData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( image ); // get PNG representation
    imagePNG = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    return imagePNG;
}
```

i tried to screenshots my iphone screen to save a picture into my camera roll.
but encountered this error. anybody know if there is an issues with my code ?

```
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationAddImage image parameter is nil
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
May 22 14:13:34 unknown assetsd[281] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
```

code:

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

    self.imageOverlay.alpha = 1;
    self.savedImage = [self maskImage:self.imgView withMask:self.baseImgView];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.savedImage, self, @selector(imageSavedToPhotosAlbum: didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), nil);
}


- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImageView *)maskImage withMask:(UIImageView *)cropImage
{

    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIImage *imagePNG = nil;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(cropImage.frame.size.width, cropImage.frame.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, 0.0); //retina res
    [self.viewForImg.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

    NSData *imgData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( image ); // get PNG representation
    imagePNG = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation

    return imagePNG;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen if the `CGSize` you're passing to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` is `CGSizeZero`. I suppose the `cropImage` argument is either `nil` or its size is `CGSizeZero`. Please debug and make sure you have all objects initialized and with correct frames.

Comment: Did you debug to see if when that happens your cropImage is either empty or has zero size?

Comment: i just put in an nslog...this bug is really random not everytime it will come out. will keep you update once this bug is back.
thanks graver

Comment: Got this error
"Failed to encode image for saved photos." UserInfo=0x3e7170 {NSUnderlyingError=0x389310 "Failed to encode image for saved photos.", NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to encode image for saved photos.

Comment: The cause for this error is saving a photo with width 0 and height 0, which proves my point in the answer, so you better search the problem somewhere else. Getting the image, setting `self.baseImgView` property or something else, but indeed that's the problem.

Comment: i actually changed the CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(480,320)
but still the same. the self.imgView and self.baseImgView are all linked with iboutlet

Comment: No, the problem is with the self.baseImgView this comes empty at some point... So see the code where you set this..

Comment: Hi graver, will you be able to help me take a look on my code ?
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/418769/imageChallengeViewController.h
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/418769/imageChallengeViewController.m

Comment: I just took a look at your code and it seems you never set the property `self.baseImgView` to something else than nil in this class. Take a look where you set this property outside of this class and see in which case it becomes empty. If your code crashes randomly, probably there is a case, where you set this property with empty UIImage.

Comment: i created a capture session manager to help capturing the images from image capture view.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/418769/CaptureSessionManager.m
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/418769/imageCaptureViewController.m

Comment: i called this to pass the images

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"imageCaptureToImageChallenge"]) {
        imageChallengeViewController *imageChall = [segue destinationViewController];
        //qrToText.textFromScanner = self.scanResult;
        imageChall.imageCaptured = self.capturedImage.image;
        imageChall.fromSample = self.fromSample;
        imageChall.overlay1or2 = self.overlay1or2;

        ////NSLog(@"text scanner %@",qrToText.textFromScanner);
    }
}